# Could not load user profile - SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm getting

> "could not load user profile"

error every time I try to access any of the sites in my SharePoint 2010 portal.
This error goes away for a week or so when I restart the server.

Please help.

Comment: Is the user profile service running on at least one server in the farm? Is the user profile synchronisation servive running on at least one server in the farm (for this, check on the server on which it is supposed to be running that the FIM services are actually running from the server OS services screen rather than fron within SharePoint)?

Comment: I have only one server in my farm. The FIM service is running but the FIMsynchronization service is not running. The user profile synchronization service (CA -> system settings -> services on server) is stuck on stopping. I did not understand how to check if the FIM is running from server OS services rather than from within sharepoint.

Comment: Try stopping the USP Synch service by using the following powershell command: Get-spserviceinstance | ? {$_.Typename -eq "User Profile Synchronization Service"} | Stop-SPServiceInstance. Often this will stop the service successfully. When the service is on Status "Stopped" try starting the service again by using | Start-SPServiceInstance.

Comment: In addition to SunP's answer, please check the ULS logs and Events in Event Viewer. Share if you find anything unusual. FIM Synchronization must be running for UPS Synchronization startup. Do not start the FIM services manually. UPS will automatically start it for you. You have to only make sure that there is nothing UPS to perform its actions.

Comment: If you are having issues with the user profile sync service, it's worth looking at http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx as there's lots of useful information on getting everything sorted correctly to allow the user profile sync service to start.

Answer (score 0):

This is may occur if

1. This issue might occur if The User Profile Synchronization Service has been configured more than once and the UPS service application that associated to Main web application differ from the UPS service that associated to My Site.

**To check web application services connection**

> Central Administration > Application Management > Manage web
>   applications > Service Connections.

Make sure that a User Profile service application is checked and set as the default.

You can also check a similar scenario to your issue at [could not load user profile](https://blog.devoworx.net/2013/01/05/service-application-associations-in-sharepoint-2010/)

2. Also it may occur if the UPS has been deleted or stopped and stuck.

   - In this case you can also check [User Profile Synchronization Service Stuck on ‘Starting’](https://blog.devoworx.net/2013/01/14/user-profile-sync-service-stuck-on-starting/)
   - [User Profile Synchronization Service Starting then Stopped in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/02/05/user-profile-synchronization-service-starting-and-stoped/)

Comment: I am also here If you need more clarification